# Using tile layers in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, tile-package, tile-layer

I worked with ArcGIS for Desktop 10.3.1 to do some geomorphologic analysis, which resulted in a few raster layers (all in GeoTIFF format).

I want to publish them to ArcGIS online, in order to make a Web App for presenting those maps.

I uploaded the GeoTIFF rasters as a Tile Package (Create Map Tile Package function) and used Publish to convert it to a Tile Layer (online).
All good so far.

The problem is I can't choose which raster to display in an online map. It only shows me the one which had its check mark on, when I created the Tile Package in ArcGIS for Desktop... I can't choose another one from the list, in order to make it visible (see the picture).

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is it a known limitation of ArcGIS Online?

I am using an Esri Developer account on Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0, Windows 10 Home 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented by @RussRoberts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209438/using-tile-layers-in-arcgis-online/212931#comment319463_209438):

> You could do this workflow in ArcMap (or Pro) Run - Manage Tile Cache
> tool on the layer, then run Export Tile Cache tool and select the
> output as tile package. This will work around having to create a
> separate mxd for each layer.